# Suitable category for low quality post

Tags: discussion, review-queues, low-quality-posts

While reviewing the Low Quality post queue I came across this answer (probably):

[Question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/13670042)

It looks like a review audit type to me, but I couldn't find any suitable category to recommend deletion. To me it doesn't look any way related to the question, so I don't find any of the given categories to recommend deletion for this answer.

It feels like a spam to some extent. So under which category should I put this answer?

Comment: _No comment needed_

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Leaving a comment is *optional*. It's clear that this answer doesn't belong on the site, explanation is not needed in this case.

[image]

Comment: shouldn't there be category to mark these types of questions/answers as spam?

Comment: @VivekMishra you can always open the question in another screen and mark it as 'abusive' - that's the correct flag for this kind of content.

Comment: As this was a review audit so I was not able to find that answer when I opened it in new tab. By the way will do it in future scenarios